# How can I format the x axis scale to a logarithmic scale in the android library GraphView?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I want to port a Bode Chart application from PC to Android devices. I found this library (GraphView) to plot in a simply way in Android. The only problem that stop me is that I cannot find a solution to set a logarithmic scale for my graphs. I need it because they're supposed to be in a Bode Chart for the correct plotting.
In the other Java libraries for PC plotting I used simply a method called setDomainAxis and I give to it a NumberAxis or in my case a LogAxis.
I found out a method to set min and max range value but no min and max domain value method founded and no reference in their documentation.
Did someone find a fix, a solution to this scaling problem?
Thanks to anyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple solution using native components to plot a Logarithmic background and plot [here](https://github.com/binujayaram/LogarithmicGraphForAndroid), so, no third party library dependencies.

To smooth-out the curves, you can use any available Bezier Curve alogorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box, but you can do the trick yourself with label formatting and feeding in skewed data.
There is a demo on label formatting here:

[CustomLabelFormatterActivity](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos/blob/master/graphviewdemos/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphviewdemos/CustomLabelFormatterActivity.java)

You feed in the logarithmic data, and for the labels you do the corresponding (reverse, I believe) transformation in the setCustomLabelFormatter method for the y axis.